# Why does overloading math operators in python depend on what order it is used?

Tags: python-3.x, operator-overloading

If I create a class such as 'A' below:

```
class A(object): 
     a = 1 
     def __truediv__(self, var): 
         return self.a / var
```

and then try to divide an int by A as:

```
print(3 / A())
```

python raises a TypeError. However, if I divide an int by this object python prints:

```
print(A() / 3)
```

python prints 0.333333.

How can I make the class work so that I can perform mathematical operations in any order?

N.B. Numpy arrays seem to be able to work both ways i.e:

```
import numpy as np

1 / np.arange(1, 5)
np.arange(1, 5) / 1
```

runs and works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also implement the reflected dunder methods. In your case, that's `__rtruediv__()`